# xpath for table caption according to known nested td element

Tags: html, xpath, selenium

I am stuck trying to create xpath for a caption according to known td class.

```
<tr>
<td class="...">
    <table class="...">
        ...
    </table>
</td>   
<td class="...">    
    <table class="...">
        <caption class="...">CAPTION_WANTED</caption>
        <colgroup>
            ...
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            ...
            <tr class="...">
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr class="...">
                ...
                <td class="...">
                    ...
                </td>
                <td class="TD_KNOWN">
                    <div class="...">...</div>
                </td>
                ...
            </tr>
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
...
```

I tried this one: `//*tr[KNOWN_ID]/td/table[tbody[tr[td[@class,"TD_KNOWN"]]]]/caption` but it didn't work.
Should I use square brackets when I want smth that contains smth that contains smth...?

Comment: WebDriver could not locate an element

Comment: can you pls give the output you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these XPaths:

```
//td[@class="TD_KNOWN"]/../../../caption
```

or

```
//td[@class="TD_KNOWN"]/ancestor::table[1]/caption
```

applied to your input XML will yield:

```
<caption class="...">CAPTION_WANTED</caption>
```

per your request.

If you want the text itself, just append `/text()` to either of the above XPaths.  For example,

```
//td[@class="TD_KNOWN"]/ancestor::table[1]/caption/text()
```

will yield

```
CAPTION_WANTED
```